# Mockserver maven plugin: init mockserver expectations from file

Tags: maven-failsafe-plugin, integration-testing, mockserver

I'm using Mockserver maven plugin to mock some requests for integration tests.

My pom.xml looks like:

```
        ...

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockserver-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <serverPort>1080</serverPort>
                <logLevel>DEBUG</logLevel>
                <initializationClass>com.mycompany.ExampleInitializationClass</initializationClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>run-mockserver</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-mockserver</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        ...
```

Problem here is that I have to provide expectations using a class (`com.mycompany.ExampleInitializationClass`) and I want to provide expectations using a JSON file like described here:

http://www.mock-server.com/mock_server/initializing_expectations.html

I didn't find any way in the plugin configuration to initialize the Mockserver with the property:

`-Dmockserver.initializationJsonPath`

Is there any way to achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to define `initializationJson` property specifying path to JSON file with expectations:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockserver-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <serverPort>1080</serverPort>
        <logLevel>DEBUG</logLevel>
        <initializationJson>expectations.json</initializationJson>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        ...
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The catch here is that the file path is relative to `testClasspath` directory (e.g. `${project.basedir}/target/test-classes/`), so you have to copy the expectation file there. You may use e.g. maven-antrun-plugin for this (as below) or 
maven-resources-plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <copy file="your/expectations.json" todir="${project.basedir}/target/test-classes/"/>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```